# Java Stream Api - complicated calculation during reduction

Tags: java, java-stream

is there some me better way how to do more complicated calculation in reduction than this (check getCurrentBalance):

```java
@Override
    public Map<User, BigDecimal> getTotalExpensesForUsers(Group group) {
        return group.getExpenses().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Expense::getUser,
                        Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, Expense::getAmount, BigDecimal::add)
                ));
    }

    @Override
    public Map<User, BigDecimal> getCurrentBalance(Group group) {
        final var defaultTotalWeight = BigDecimal.valueOf(group.getDefaultTotalWeight());
        var totalExpensesPerUser = getTotalExpensesForUsers(group);
        final var averageExpensePerUser = totalExpensesPerUser.values().stream()
                .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add)
                .divide(defaultTotalWeight);

        totalExpensesPerUser.entrySet()
                .forEach(e -> e.setValue(e.getValue().subtract(averageExpensePerUser)));
        return totalExpensesPerUser;
    }
```

I would like to somehow put it to one stream because currently I am iterating over the collection multiple times. Or is this case when I should use for loop instead?

P.S. hopefully is the meaning of the code self explaining if not, I will update the question

**EDITED**
Because I got a lot of responses that it is not possible to do it in one iteration I am updating this question. I know it is not possible to do it in one iteration, but like this I am able to do it with two:

```java
@Override
    public Map<User, BigDecimal> getCurrentBalanceAlternative(Group group) {
        var currentBalance = new HashMap<User, BigDecimal>();
        final var defaultTotalWeight = BigDecimal.valueOf(group.getDefaultTotalWeight());
        var totalExpense = BigDecimal.ZERO;

        for(Expense expense: group.getExpenses()){
            var expenseUser = expense.getUser();
            var expenseAmount = expense.getAmount();

            totalExpense = totalExpense.add(expenseAmount);

            currentBalance.put(expenseUser, currentBalance.getOrDefault(expenseUser, BigDecimal.ZERO).add(expenseAmount));
        }

        var averageExpensePerUser = totalExpense.divide(defaultTotalWeight);
        currentBalance.entrySet()
                .forEach(e -> e.setValue(e.getValue().subtract(averageExpensePerUser)));

        return currentBalance;
    }
```

but with streams I had to calculate the totalExpense separately.

Comment: There's not going to be any way to do this without multiple iterations, whether you use streams or loops.

Comment: **1.** *iterating over the collection multiple times* - you can't subtract the *average* before it has been calculated, makes sense? Therefore, it needs to be done in two iterations doesn't matter with streams or with loops. **2.** *put it to one stream* - that isn't a good idea because you need to change the state of each `User` object (now you're not using streams and that's fine), and if you would succeed in that intention it will not give you any advantage because code would become more convoluted.